# IDE CVS checkout from a tag

Tags: eclipse, cvs, vcs-checkout

I was wondering if there is a clean way of checking out code from CVS for a given tag from cvs repository perspective (tag from production to maintain and patch that work space).

I know that we can check out code from head and replace the all projects with the tag. But if I have to do it cleanly by just creating new workspace and then just given a tag checkout all files and projects associated with that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checkout specific TAG using either [CVS Repositories view](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-32.htm&cp=0_4_2_4) or [CVS Checkout wizard](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-40a.htm).

Comment: Thanks. But if you have to check-out projects as different names it becomes tough to rename and go to each sub-folder in CVS. What I was looking for is automatically it checksout all the projects associated with a given tag.

Comment: The original question didn't say anything about renaming, but you get the project list and can select them all for checkout from CVS Repositories view. As for renaming projects, for Maven projects you can do that with m2e extension for CVS or using generic Maven SCM wizard.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt mention about renaming before. We are not using maven. I think there is no easy way of renaming, atleast your answer helped. Thanks.

Comment: The old m2e's wizards that I've implemented used to offer import existing Eclipse projects if it can't find pom.xml, then you could specify common suffix or prefix for those imported Eclipse projects. But I am not sure if that feature is still there.